# Problem with tabs not being added to Page

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm creating a project where I need to get 5 tabs to be shown at the front page of my app and navigate through them. 

I was following this tutorial from this two links and adapting at my way https://medium.com/@eijaz/getting-started-with-tablayout-in-android-kotlin-bb7e21783761 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNpWGI_hGGg&t=68s (adapting this one to Kotlin), but when I compile and run it, it just shows the screen without the tabs, like a blank page. How can I proceed? I really couldn't find the error.

### This is the Adapter I used

```
class SectionsAdapter(fm: FragmentManager?) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {
    private val listOfTabs = mutableListOf<Fragment>()

    private val listOfTabsTitle = mutableListOf<String>()

    fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment, title: String ) {
        listOfTabs.add(fragment)
        listOfTabsTitle.add(title)
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence {
        return listOfTabsTitle[position]
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {
        return listOfTabs[position]
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return listOfTabs.size
    }
```

### This is what I have into the main class

```
private fun setupSectionsAdapter() {
        var adapter = SectionsAdapter(supportFragmentManager)

        with(adapter) {
            addFragment(Tab1Fragment(), "Tab1")
            addFragment(Tab2Fragment(), "Tab2")
            addFragment(Tab3Fragment(), "Tab3")
            addFragment(Tab4Fragment(), "Tab4")
            addFragment(Tab5Fragment(), "Tab5")
        }

        container.adapter = adapter
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(container as ViewPager)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setupSectionsAdapter()
        container.addOnPageChangeListener(TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabs))
        tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(container))

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_of_items)    
    }
```

### The fragment class

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false)

        return view
    }

    companion object {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private val ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number"

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        fun newInstance(sectionNumber: Int): Tab1Fragment {
            val fragment = Tab1Fragment()
            val args = Bundle()
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber)
            fragment.arguments = args
            return fragment
        }
    }
```

### This is the XML for the fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="AJASDAJSD"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

### This is the XML for the page I'm trying to implement the tabs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ListOfItems">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">



        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Do you know what am I missing? Upfront, sorry if it is doubled, but I couldn't find anything similar to my problem here.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you call `setContentView ` before `setupSectionsAdapter`?

Comment: Hi Ali, I did it but doesn't seem to be the problem. I still not having the tabs shown :(